# does using 'UIA' Backend in Pywinauto to access MFC application elements cause crash of application?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, pywinauto

Iam using Pywinauto to validate UI Elements through Automated scripts , Our Application Under Test is MFC type , but Iam using UIA Backend to access AUT via Pywinauto because when I use Inspect.exe to get properties ,and it shows most of elements details in UIAutomation mode . but some times Application crashes , its not consistant and not crashing at the same place of validation , it changes all the time
(MFC Application and python 3.7.5 installed both are 64 bit,pywinauto is 0.6.8 )
I dont understand is it because of UIA method Iam using for MFC application ?

one more thing I want to add here is we are  accessing  Pywinauto scripts as a customlibrary  in  Robot framework and running tests with Robot

and I have written 3 Classes in 3 different .py files
1)ConnectClass to for connection with app

2)details about each elements in another class, here Iam importing connectionClass to get the app Object

3)in the 3rd file I have added the validation functions inside a class, this class inherits the 2nd Class , these functions will be the interface for Robot framework

I just wanted to understand why the crash is happening , what is the wrong method Iam following here above?